# How to save 2 entities using Magical Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I want to save 2 entities (Person, Group) together using Magical Record.

```
//Model
// Person : name (Relationship : group 'To One')
// Group  : groupName (Relationship : person 'To Many')
```

"person.name" can be saved, but "person.group.groupName" can't be saved.

"person.group.groupName" is nil when I check in NSLog.

"self.groupName.text" is the correct value.

It should be noted, "self.groupName.text" is selected in UIPickerView data that has been registered in advance. Therefore, can not use [Group MR_createEntity].

Please tell me how to resolve. Thank you.

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Person.h"
#import "Group.h"

@class Person, Group;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) Person *person;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Person.h"
#import "Group.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

{
    BOOL isDispGroupPicker;
    UIPickerView *picker;
    int selectedGroupRow;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *groupField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *accessoryView;
- (IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.nameField.delegate = self;
    self.groupField.delegate = self;
    isDispGroupPicker = NO;

    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 550, 320, 180);
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.tag = 1;
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - save

- (IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
    Person *person = [Person MR_createEntity];
    person.name = _nameField.text;
    //person.group.groupName = _groupField.text;

    Group *group = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:selectedGroupRow];
    person.group.groupName = group.groupName;

    NSLog(@"%@",group.groupName);       // OK
    NSLog(@"%@",person.group.groupName);// null->NG

    [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
}

#pragma mark - keyboard

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    BOOL ret = YES;
    if (textField == _nameField) {
        if(isDispGroupPicker) {
            [self hidePicker];
            [_accessoryView removeFromSuperview];
        }

    } else if (textField == _groupField) {
        [_nameField resignFirstResponder];
        if(!isDispGroupPicker) {
            picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 550, 320, 216);
            [self showPicker];
            [self inputPickerClose];
            isDispGroupPicker = YES;
        }
        ret = NO;
    }
    return ret;
}

#pragma mark - FetchedResultsController

- (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController
{
    if(_fetchedResultsController == nil){
        self.fetchedResultsController = [Group MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"groupName" ascending:YES withPredicate:nil groupBy:nil delegate:self];
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

#pragma mark - GroupPicker

- (void)showPicker {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 320, 320, 216);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    Group *group = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];
    return group.groupName;
}

- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    Group *group = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];
    self.groupField.text = group.groupName;
    selectedGroupRow = row;
}

- (void)inputPickerClose {
    _accessoryView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,310,320,44)];
    _accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_accessoryView];

    UIButton* closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(230,10,100,27);
    [closeButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIButton* cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,10,100,27);
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneGroup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelGroup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_accessoryView addSubview:closeButton];
    [_accessoryView addSubview:cancelButton];
}

- (void)doneGroup:(id)sender {
    [self hidePicker];
    [_accessoryView removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)cancelGroup:(id)sender {
    [self hidePicker];
    [_accessoryView removeFromSuperview];
    _groupField.text = nil;
}

- (void)hidePicker {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 600, 320, 216);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    isDispGroupPicker = NO;
}

@end
```

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Group;

@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Group *group;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picker should pick Group (displaying name) not group.name, then you set person.group = group.

—update

Now, on the picker you choose group name and you try to attach that name to person.group.name, but person.group is nil at that time, so your code does nothing. So, your picker must return you a Group object, not only it’s name - you may load all groups to NSArray and pick it’s index from picker position. After that you will have properly choosen Group object which you will attach to Person object (person.group).

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Please tell me more.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the meaning that you say, but I don't know the way. I'm programming beginner, and try to resolve in a way that I think you say, but it's not working. I uploaded all code. Would you please point out the code?

Comment: It was resolved to try several times. Thank you so much.